# Upload of MediaFiles is always returning NullPointException

Tags: android

I am encountering this weird error when uploading voice recordings from the Android device to an backend.

I am getting the following error and nothing is uploaded:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.fixSlashes (File.java.=:205)

The file name consists of the data timestamp, I have tried without data timestamp and still have the same error.

The weird part is that, I have tested with textfiles and it gets uploaded without any issue nor exception.

Anyone knows what's the issue?

Comment: please post the code and stacttrace

Comment: @Sas The logcat output is already mentioned above: java.lang....

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve it. I declared an static string and assign the filepath to it. I used that string to point to the file to upload.

Somehow if I don't declare it as a static string after assigning the filepath, it becomes null when I point to it for upload.